# Queues service that allows to query messages list

Tags: queue, message-queue

Looking for a message queues software, that would allow to make simple queries on queued messages list.
For example to tag messages with userid, and to receive all messages in queue related to the particular user later.

Answer (score 0):

Although i personally never used this, it seems like SQL Server's [Service broker](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/21/sql-server-intorduction-to-service-broker-and-sample-script/) (introduced in 2005) can do the job. 

 You can [query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166127%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) the queue as any other table, and gather the informatin you need about the messages

P.S oracle also have a queueing infrastracture within their dbs, if you prefer it to mssql